# Google map issue on Newspaper theme

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

The event calendar plugin map is not working on newspaper theme. While click on zoom in and zoom out.

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMhJM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue regarding CSS conflict.

**You need to overwrite with this CSS.**

```
body.tribe_events-template-default .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb,
body.tribe_events-template-default .post img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```